# Is FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE broken, or wrong, or both?

Tags: android, notifications

From the android documentation on [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html):

```
FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE
```

> Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if you
>   want the sound and/or vibration play each time the notification is
>   sent, even if it has not been canceled before that.

Doesn't this description seem like the opposite of what it should be? Also, if I want the notification to alert every time, should I OR this onto the flags field or not? I'm also seeing conflicting claims of if this 'works' .... whatever that means!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some testing, it seems that FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE does what it is named, not what the API description says.

To have a notification alert every time it is issued, make sure you do not OR the FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE bit into the notification.flags.

I've issued a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33003

Comment: So I can assume it will actually alert every time if I OR this FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE ?

Comment: No, read the answer again... ORing FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE does what its name says it will do. :)

Comment: I got confused... I did OR this FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE to my notification flag, but it still do notify (sound / vibrate) every time.

Comment: @RRTW - that should work, include your code to make sure it was done correctly.

Comment: Notification sound playing in infinite loop :(